# Rotated rectangle has differerent image size

Tags: geometry

Why when I rotate rectangle its size gets bigger? How can I fixed? Thanks.

```
{n, m} = {2, 3}; ro = 0.6;

SeedRandom[123];
mat = RandomChoice[{{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}, {n, m}];

mat2 = Table[{{1, 1}, {3, 2}, Flatten[mat, 1][[i]]}, {i, n*m}];

Grid[Partition[
  Which[#[[3]] == {1, 3}, 
     Graphics[{Cyan, Rectangle[#[[1]], #[[2]], RoundingRadius -> ro]}],
     #[[3]] == {1, 4}, 
     Graphics[{Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
       Rectangle[#[[1]], #[[2]], RoundingRadius -> ro]}],
     #[[3]] == {2, 3}, 
     Graphics[{Cyan, 
       Rotate[Rectangle[#[[1]], #[[2]], RoundingRadius -> ro], 
        90 \[Degree]]}],
     #[[3]] == {2, 4}, 
     Graphics[{Lighter[Blue, 0.5], 
       Rotate[Rectangle[#[[1]], #[[2]], RoundingRadius -> ro], 
        90 \[Degree]]}]] & /@ mat2, m], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example showing the issue, and giving a workaround

```
With[
    {
        rectangle = Rectangle[{1, 1}, {3, 2}],
        rotation = Rotate[#, 90 Degree]&
    },
    Row @ {
        Graphics @ rectangle,
        Graphics @ rotation @ rectangle,
        rotation @ Graphics @ rectangle
    }
]
```

[image]

Comment: So, order matters. Thanks. It worked excellently.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to set the image size directly. E.g.,

```
{n, m} = {2, 3}; ro = 0.6;
SeedRandom[123];
pts = RandomChoice[{{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}, n*m]
mat2 = Map[{{1, 1}, {3, 2}, #} &, pts]
f[pt_] := With[{
   row1 = {1, 1},
   row2 = {3, 2},
   color = <|3 -> Cyan, 4 -> Lighter[Blue, 0.5]|>[Part[pt, 2]],
   angle = <|1 -> 0, 2 -> 90 Degree|>[Part[pt, 1]]
   },
  Graphics[{color, 
    Rotate[Rectangle[row1, row2, RoundingRadius -> ro], angle]},
   ImageSize -> {100, 100}]
  ]
Grid[Partition[f /@ pts, m], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]